# difficulty with .push() when making array groups

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a little script that goes through the array 'CA' and for each element makes several new arrays that take wrap-around sections of 'CA', all centered at that element. Here is the code:

```js
var max = 10,
  thisVar = {}
CA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    thisVar["groupS" + j + "C" + i] = [CA[i]]

    for (a = 1; a <= j; a++) {

      if ((i - a) < 0) {
        thisVar["groupS" + j + "C" + i].unshift(CA.reverse()[-(((i + 1) - a) % max)])
      } else {
        thisVar["groupS" + j + "C" + i].unshift(CA[(i - a)])
      }

      thisVar["groupS" + j + "C" + i].push(CA[((i + a) % max)])
    }
  }
}

console.log(thisVar.groupS1C0);
```

This returns ['j', 'a', 'i'] but I was expecting ['j', 'a', 'b']. It seems the problem is the .push() but surely in this case the variable 'a' is 1?

Comment: I get invalid javascript on the last line here.

Comment: can you make a graphic, that shows the result in a table, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @KjetilNordin, the variables are being created golbally.

Comment: I think this look like an exciting challenge, but I am having a hard time understanding the concept without an understanding of the global variables. But if @Ashwin 's answer is what you need, feel free to ignore me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.Just reverse CA and push it.You will get your expected output ['j', 'a', 'b'].

```js
max = 10
CA = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

for (j=0; j<5; j++){
for (i=0; i<max; i++) {
this["groupS" + j + "C" + i] = [CA[i]]

for (a=1; a<=j; a++) {

if ((i-a) < 0) {
this["groupS" + j + "C" + i].unshift(CA.reverse()[-(((i+1) - a) % max)])
}
else {
this["groupS" + j + "C" + i].unshift(CA[(i-a)])
}

this["groupS" + j + "C" + i].push(CA.reverse()[((i+a) % max)])
}
}
}

console.log(groupS1C0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realise that using CA.reverse() in creating the 'group' variables alters CA.. I thought it was just creating a new array. I was able to solve the issue by using CA.reverse() again in the if statement.